# Searching byte[] in Linq can't use Contains function

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to search a `byte[]` column in a sql database using a `byte[]` as the input type to the query using Entity Framework 6.  If it was a string field I could use the Contains function which would work fine. The field has been encrypted now so I need to achieve the same search but now with `byte[]`.

The error message I get is:

> `byte[]` does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

so what should I use here. All the fields in the example below are type byte[].

```
  (from v in db.Vendors
  where v.Code.Contains(item.Code) ||
  v.TradingName == item.TradingName
  select v).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: item.Code is also a byte[], or just a single byte ?

Comment: hi Luc it's a byte[]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to reality. Binary fields CAN NOT BE SEARCHED IN SQL. Whoever decided to use encryption for field values - obviously forgot to make his homework about what it means. On top, seriously, if this approach of yours works - he also implemented an idiotic (as in: extremely easy to crack) encryption scheme.

Comment: Hi TomTom he is just following the approach outlined here: https://janhannemann.wordpress.com/2013/11/10/simple-encryption-for-windows-winrt-and-windows-phone/ it wasn't until I started to change the methods around we ran into this issue.  Maybe using a symmetric key within sql might be a better approach?

Comment: Tat approach would require loading and decrypting all data to then search on the decrypted data. It works - and is slow. Use SQL Server encryption methods. Row & Field level security coming this year with sql 2016.

Comment: Hi TomTom thanks for your response, we are at a loss how to encrypt data in SQL but be able to search on it unless as you said and we have found out pulling it all out decrypting it then searching which is too slow.  We have looked at this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/08/27/using-always-encrypted-with-entity-framework-6/  will have a look at SQL Server encryption methods. Thanks

Comment: There is normally no need to encrypt data - sql server can handle that itself, transparently.